# React.jsx: type is invalid expected a string, class or function but got object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-component, npm-publish

I was trying to publish my react component to NPM registry with the following configurations.

`package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "publish",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "private": false,
    "main": "public/main.bundle.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "webpack",
        "start:dev": "webpack serve --mode development"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            [
                "@babel/preset-react",
                {
                    "runtime": "automatic"
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
        "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "babel-loader": "^9.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "sass": "^1.56.0",
        "sass-loader": "^13.1.0",
        "stream": "^0.0.2",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
    }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require("path");
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
        output: {
            filename: "[name].bundle.js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
            clean: true,
        },
        mode: argv.mode === "development" ? "development" : "production",
        devServer: {
            static: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
            compress: true,
            port: 3000,
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
        },
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: "all",
            },
        },
        devtool: "inline-source-map",
        infrastructureLogging: {level: 'error'},
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.jsx$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    };
};
```

`index.js`

```js
import App from "./App.jsx"

export default App
```

`App.jsx`
Has much more than this but exports module as

```js
function App(){return <div>Hello World</div>}
export default App;
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. `npm run build` (to build chunked modules)
   [image: project structure]
   =======
2. `npm link` in current directory
3. `npm link publish` in another project (successfully adds the module)
4. I import the module as `import App from "publish"`

No any names conflicts are happening with `publish` package name.

Result:
All I get is empty object import with errors as
[image: error]

Am I not understanding how named and default import/export work? I'm confused.

Comment: why you have `export default App` again in index.js ?

Comment: in index.js you have to render the App.jsx using render method

Comment: @KcH because others will `require()` it in their projects? I don't understand your question. I export the component for external use.

Comment: @arp I have to render the component to make it availabe in external `require()` ?